# Telerik winforms right-click -> paste event?

Tags: events, telerik, telerik-grid, copy-paste, radgridview

I need to do something when a cell is modified via pasted content, I don't seem to find any event that gets fired while/after text is pasted into the cell.

I have tried:
ValueChanged
CellValidating
CellPaint
CellValuePushed
CellValueNeeded
Validating

in a desperate attempt of finding out what fires, I know some of those events obviously won't fire.

My problem is that I can't seem to catch the event of paste, I would think and hope there IS an event linked to the action.

Using RadForms 2012Q3
RadGridView control.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but there are three in WPF:

- Pasted
- Pasting
- PastingCellClipboardContent

I don't know whether WinForms is different...

Comment: unfortunately no pasting events in winforms. We eneded up capturing the event on keypress and checking for ctrl+v

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to join late the party, with Telerik WinForms to achieve the paste you have the 'Pasting' event for example ([Telerik Copy/Past/Cut docs](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/copy-paste-cut))

First, call the events on the object :

```
yourGrid.Pasting += YourGrid_Pasting;
```

Then retrieve the value and use it :

```
    private void YourGrid_Pasting(object sender, GridViewClipboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            string data = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
            if (data != string.Empty)
            {
                // data is your copied text                    
            }
        }
    }
```